# What is the difference between request.user and request.user.username?

Tags: django

As title says, what is the difference between request.user and request.user.username? I use them to compare them with some variables and sometimes it works using the first and sometimes using the second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that questions comes only after you were using user objects in your templates like `{{user}}` and `{{user.username}}` and understand that templates rendering the same.

The point is that when you render the template, django automatically converts variables to its unicode representation (strings), and in your view function it can be not a string but an instance of some model.

User class from app django.contrib.auth has a unicode representation like

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username
```

And maybe that's why you were confusing `user` and `user.username` .

This misunderstanding can be dangerous, cause when you are typing something like

```
if user1 == user2.username:
```

you won't get `TypeError`, cause any django model inhereted from models.Model has a operator

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self._get_pk_val() == other._get_pk_val()
```

which finds if user1 and user2.username had the same class.

Anyway, I think after practicing a little you'll find difference between string and objects of some model.

---

Answer (score 5):

`request.user` is the `User` instance, `request.user.username` is a string of that user's `username`.

If you have a string, e.g. `'admin'`, then you would want to compare it to the `request.user.username`.

Comment: if user names are not unique then comparing the 'user.username' is a problem. i guess comparing the instance 'user' is more convenient

Comment: @sema Django usernames *are* unique. Without knowing what the op's variables are, it's impossible to say what they should be comparing them to.